# Formula for incrementing by a constant number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, increment, worksheet-function

For a chart I need to create  a formula using: `60*(x+1)` where `x` is constantly increasing.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Enter `x` in A1, `y` in B1, in B2:

```
=60*(A2+1)
```

and copy down. Then populate A2 onwards with values of your choice.

@Derek kindly provided an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17J6Qc9XOY5spI9O4cW_AFLfGnlsZazmGXrIo7bHRN7A/edit?usp=sharing) in an answer since deleted for reasons of moderation. Beware however, since, because in Google Spreadsheets, the formulae are not quite the same.

Copying the formulae down may be easiest by grabbing the fill-handle (a little square at the bottom right-hand corner of a cell - only visible when the cell is selected) and pulling that down the screen while keeping the left mouse button depressed. To start with `1` in A2 would make sense. The same dragging approach applied to A2 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> *also* depressed should automatically create a constantly increasing series in ColumnA.

Comment: Perfect, +1, and I've withdrawn my other comments.